# I encountered this error while updating Laravel10

Tags: php, laravel

I did the update process and got this error

"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

I did the update process and got this error

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. it would be nice if you can spare time to take a [tour] and learn [ask]. it is imperative to provide [mcve] in the question to ease problem solving. those being said, could you provide the verbatim error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is conflicting requirements in your composer.json file. Each package in there will have its own set of requirements, which may contradict each other. Commonly this means multiple versions of the same package are required.

A first step is to make sure all of your required packages are using the newest stable versions available